# Asp.NET add rows to gridview one at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, timeout

I am developping an asp.NET application in c#. Basically, it's some kind of database searching app.

You enter a name in a textbox then hit the ok button and the app loops through a lotus notes database and displays all the results as rows in a gridview.

The problem is that the database has like 170 000 items.

If I search for example "James", the browser will timeout before the app finishes looping.

What I am trying to do is to immediately display the newly added row as soon as the loop adds it. A bit like this:

```
    dt.Rows.Add(param1, param2); //as soon as this line of code is done,
    //display the row in the gridview without waiting for the loop to be completed
    //then, continue the loop
```

Doing this would tell the browser that the page is still responding, so that it does not timeout before the process is completed.

Any way of doing this?

Comment: do you select all Items from the database and then  "James" from the items in the grid or do you select "James" from the items in the database?

Comment: @CasparKleijne Not sure what you mean, but it's rather a loop that gets each item in the database, one by one, and check if the name contains the entered string. If yes, then it adds a row to the gridview and if not, it continue looping to check the next one.

Comment: depending on the database you are using, nut in SQL databases you normally do something like 'SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName from Users where Name ='James'' , so iterating trough all records wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @CasparKleijne if possible, I would like to find a way of doing it without using SQL. Since the app is on a distant server and I'm working on it from my pc, and I don't have the right to install the NotesSQL driver.

Comment: @NZoth: There is little that users are going to do with 170 rows let alone 170 thousand rows.  The data being on a "distant server" is exactly what web pages do well. And it's precisely the reason you need a caching datasource.  What you are doing requires a constant connection while simultaneously refreshing the web page, this is some pretty heavy duty programming that simply is overkill for what is built in to ASP.NET.  Find a LotusNotesSql driver, enable Paging on your GridView, and be done with it.

Comment: @fnostro I tried LotusNotes sql, whenever I try to add a datasource, it prompts me an error saying stuff about 32 bit/64 bit compatibilities, and when I use the odbc data source in the SysWoW64 folder, it simply cannot find the driver. The display of the page takes 13 minutes. That is way too long when all you get at the end is 13 results for the research. At this point, you don't even remember searching something when it finishes. I know SQL would improve this a lot, but I can't make it working.

Comment: you are going to have to do your homework on how to setup LotusNotesSql.  You are likely going to have to pass it a LotusNotes compatible query string.  The query ***must*** take place on the LotusNotes side and it should return you only the results of the matching criteria.  You absolutely should not be retrieving 1 line at a time and making the criteria comparison on your side.